# MVC razor get div width and check for condition

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a view which should be responsive.My model has two properties leftPosition and topPosition.Now I want if the width of my outer div is less than 714 the topPosition and leftPosition are set to 0 else they will have the values which they receve from model.But how to check that outer div width in mvc razor syntax.I have tried to use javascript and set mvc razor variable but I found that its not possible to do such thing as asp.net is server-side and javascript is client side.

mvc partial view

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    if (Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsWidth < 1000)
     {
        {item.TopPosition = 0;}
         {item.LeftPosition = 0;}
     }
      Html.RenderPartial(@item.TileName, @item);
    }
```

Instead of this Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsWidth I want to use something like ("#desktopTilesContiner").Width,which I can use in my if condition.In my image I have different tiles - Labs,Pathology,Procedures,Medications.These are set according to their top and left position but on mobile device I just want they come in one column ignoring their top and left position.Something like the image two.

[image: tiles div]

[image: required image]

Comment: you're mixing a lot stuff here. Let the c# code take care of the initial rendering of the page. And let javascript/css take care of updating/styling the view for you

Comment: but can we set model values using javascript I mean how I should set my topPosition and leftPosition to 0 in model when div width is less than 714

Comment: why do you need the model to keep these values? this should be maintained in your css mainly

Comment: please check the images now and please suggest now how to achieve the thing I want

Answer (score 0):

Your `Request.Browser.ScreenPixelsWidth < 1000` can be taken care of with css media queries, like so:

```
@media all and (max-width: 1000px) { *content here* }
```

I would also recommend to not use `position: absolute` ( *thus negating the need for the whole top / left positioning* ) and let the DOM elements flow naturally.

Comment: But my tiles-Labs etc have drag/drop functionality.Also I need to save these positions so that on next login I can show users the position of tiles saved by them during last login

Comment: You can then negate the `position: absolute` style with `position: relative` for all your absolute positioned element inside the media query I provided above - your elements will then ( hopefully ) just follow the natural DOM flow.